# kill a process if Esc key pressed using powershell

Tags: powershell, detect

is possible to kill a process if Esc key pressed ?
I've seen someone doing a key detection but for another approach and i don't know how to modify it to serve my purpose

```
    $continue = $true
while($continue)
{

    if ([console]::KeyAvailable)
    {
        echo "Toggle with F12";
        $x = [System.Console]::ReadKey() 

        switch ( $x.key)
        {
            F12 { $continue = $false }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        $wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $wsh.SendKeys('{CAPSLOCK}')
        sleep 1
        [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wsh)| out-null
        Remove-Variable wsh
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$key = [console]::ReadKey()
write-host $key.key
if ($key.Key -eq '27') {
  "Pressed Esc"
   Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HariHaran for the quick answer !
here is how you close notepad using Esc key in powershell

```
    $key = [console]::ReadKey()
write-host $key.key
if ($key.Key -eq '27') {
  "Pressed Esc"
Stop-Process -Name "notepad"
}
```